# does NSThread create autoreleasepool automatically now?

Tags: ios, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool

I have test code like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(test) object:nil];
    [thread start];
}

-(void)test
{
    MyClass *my = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@",[my description]);
}
```

I did not create any autoreleasepool for my own thread, but when the thread exit, object "my" just dealloc.why?

even though I change my test code as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(test) object:nil];
    [thread start];
} 

-(void)test
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    MyClass *my = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@",[my description]);
}
```

I create my own autoreleasepool but not drain it when the thread exit. object "my" can still dealloc anyway. why?

I use Xcode5 and not using ARC

Comment: How are you saying your my object get released?

Comment: are you able to get required information?

Comment: because i have a  breakpoint in object "my"'s dealloc method

Answer (score 30):

It's not documented, but the answer appears to be **Yes**, on OS X 10.9+ and iOS 7+.

The Objective-C runtime is [open-source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/) so you can read the source to see what's going on. The latest version of the runtime (646, which shipped with OS X 10.10 and iOS 8) does indeed add a pool if you perform an `autorelease` without a pool on the current thread. In [NSObject.mm](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-646/runtime/NSObject.mm):

```
static __attribute__((noinline))
id *autoreleaseNoPage(id obj)
{
    // No pool in place.
    assert(!hotPage());

    if (obj != POOL_SENTINEL  &&  DebugMissingPools) {
        // We are pushing an object with no pool in place, 
        // and no-pool debugging was requested by environment.
        _objc_inform("MISSING POOLS: Object %p of class %s "
                     "autoreleased with no pool in place - "
                     "just leaking - break on "
                     "objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug", 
                     (void*)obj, object_getClassName(obj));
        objc_autoreleaseNoPool(obj);
        return nil;
    }

    // Install the first page.
    AutoreleasePoolPage *page = new AutoreleasePoolPage(nil);
    setHotPage(page);

    // Push an autorelease pool boundary if it wasn't already requested.
    if (obj != POOL_SENTINEL) {
        page->add(POOL_SENTINEL);
    }

    // Push the requested object.
    return page->add(obj);
}
```

This function is called when you push the first pool (in which case the thing pushed is `POOL_SENTINEL`), or you autorelease with no pool. When the first pool is pushed, it sets up the autorelease stack. But as you see from the code, as long as the `DebugMissingPools` environmental variable is not set (it's not set by default), when autorelease is done with no pool, it also sets up the autorelease stack, and then pushes a pool (pushes a `POOL_SENTINEL`).

Similarly, (it's a little hard to follow without looking at the other code, but this is the relevant part) when the thread is destroyed (and the Thread-Local Storage is destroyed), it releases everything in the autorelease stack (that's what the `pop(0);` does) so it doesn't rely on the user to pop the last pool:

```
static void tls_dealloc(void *p) 
{
    // reinstate TLS value while we work
    setHotPage((AutoreleasePoolPage *)p);
    pop(0);
    setHotPage(nil);
}
```

The previous version of the runtime (551.1, which came with OS X 10.9 and iOS 7), also did this, as you can see from its [NSObject.mm](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/runtime/NSObject.mm):

```
static __attribute__((noinline))
id *autoreleaseSlow(id obj)
{
    AutoreleasePoolPage *page;
    page = hotPage();

    // The code below assumes some cases are handled by autoreleaseFast()
    assert(!page || page->full());

    if (!page) {
        // No pool. Silently push one.
        assert(obj != POOL_SENTINEL);

        if (DebugMissingPools) {
            _objc_inform("MISSING POOLS: Object %p of class %s "
                         "autoreleased with no pool in place - "
                         "just leaking - break on "
                         "objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug", 
                         (void*)obj, object_getClassName(obj));
            objc_autoreleaseNoPool(obj);
            return nil;
        }

        push();
        page = hotPage();
    }

    do {
        if (page->child) page = page->child;
        else page = new AutoreleasePoolPage(page);
    } while (page->full());

    setHotPage(page);
    return page->add(obj);
}
```

But the version before that (532.2, which came with OS X 10.8 and iOS 6), [does not](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/NSObject.mm):

```
static __attribute__((noinline))
id *autoreleaseSlow(id obj)
{
    AutoreleasePoolPage *page;
    page = hotPage();

    // The code below assumes some cases are handled by autoreleaseFast()
    assert(!page || page->full());

    if (!page) {
        assert(obj != POOL_SENTINEL);
        _objc_inform("Object %p of class %s autoreleased "
                     "with no pool in place - just leaking - "
                     "break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug", 
                     obj, object_getClassName(obj));
        objc_autoreleaseNoPool(obj);
        return NULL;
    }

    do {
        if (page->child) page = page->child;
        else page = new AutoreleasePoolPage(page);
    } while (page->full());

    setHotPage(page);
    return page->add(obj);
}
```

Note that the above works for any `pthread`s, not just `NSThread`s.

So basically, if you are running on OS X 10.9+ or iOS 7+, autoreleasing on a thread without a pool should not lead to a leak. This is not documented and is an internal implementation detail, so be careful relying on this as Apple could change it in a future OS. However, I don't see any reason why they would remove this feature as it is simple and only has benefits and no downsides, unless they completely re-write the way autorelease pools work or something.

Comment: Outstanding answer. Great detective work. Thanks for posting. (Voted)

Comment: Note that the automatic cleanup does *not* happen for the main thread. The cleanup function `tls_dealloc` is a thread-local-storage (TLS) destructor, added by a call to `pthread_key_init_np`. These destructors are called from `pthread_exit`, which gets implicitly called when a thread returns  from its start routine, but not in the case of the main thread. So the implicit pool added by `autoreleaseNoPage` will not be drained. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html

Comment: Confirmed by Quinn: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114025

Answer (score 1):

[**Apple documentation says**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/) (4<sup>th</sup> paragraph):

> You create an `NSAutoreleasePool` object with the usual alloc and
>   init messages and dispose of it with drain (or release—to understand
>   the difference, see Garbage Collection). Since you cannot retain an
>   autorelease pool (or autorelease it—see retain and autorelease),
>   draining a pool ultimately has the effect of deallocating it. You
>   should always drain an autorelease pool in the same context
>   (invocation of a method or function, or body of a loop) that it was
>   created. See Using Autorelease Pool Blocks for more details.