# whether should I create autoreleasepool if I detach a new thread

Tags: autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

[NSAutoreleasePool](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsautoreleasepool#1651513),
as the document says, “if you detach a thread — you need to create your own autorelease pool.” 
Previously，I thought when detach a thread, it maybe cause memory leaks, but when I was testing, there was no leaks.
So how to explain The document? Does it still need a autorelease pool?
Can you help me?  Thanks very much!

Comment: in the new thread, I add the autoreleased object, eg: `People *p = [People peopleWithName:@"test"];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [does NSThread create autoreleasepool automatically now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952549/does-nsthread-create-autoreleasepool-automatically-now)