# Do I need an autoreleasepool block inside a DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

Using swift 3 in Xcode 8.2.1 for an iOS App.

I understand that I need an autoreleasepool block when dispatching some processing on a new thread. But is it needed when dispatching back on main thread ?

Suppose we are on the main thread and do the following:

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        autoreleasepool {
            //***** do something in the background
        } // autoreleasepool

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //***** do something on the main thread when background job is done
            //***** does this something need to be enclosed in an autoreleasepool block ?
        } // DispatchQueue.main.async

    } // DispatchQueue.global
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

DispatchQueue has an "autorelease frequency" attribute, which decides if every workitem is automatically surrounded by `autorelease{}` or not. It's documented in `dispatch/queue.h` and not in Apple's documentation, so I can't link to it; attaching screenshots from the headers.

- `DispatchQueue.main` has autorelease frequency `.workitem` (which means autorelease each dispatch_async)
- `DispatchQueue.global` has it set to `.never` (never autorelease automatically; it's up to you)
- `DispatchQueue.init` creates one set to `.inherit`. By default, a new queue targets the global queue, which means it's implicitly `.never`.

[image: documentation screenshot of .never]

Note that this attribute only applies to `.async()`. If you do `.sync()`, you must always manually manage the autorelease situation.

[image: docu screenshot of dispatch_sync]

To answer your question: No. On main thread, you don't have to wrap your async block with `autorelease{}`. For any other queue, you either need to set the attribute or manually wrap in `autorelease{}`.

I recommend never dispatching directly to `DispatchQueue.global` if there's a risk something would be autoreleased, as that would either leak or end up in a never-emptied pool. Instead, create your own queues with explicit autorelease pool policy.

Comment: Could you link to the docs where these screenshots are from?

Comment: @tmm1 `DISPATCH_AUTORELEASE_FREQUENCY_NEVER` is at https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/f13ea5dcc055e5d2d7c02e90d8c9907ca9dc72e1/dispatch/queue.h#L745-L748

Comment: @tmm1 and the blurb about autorelease frequency is at https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/f13ea5dcc055e5d2d7c02e90d8c9907ca9dc72e1/dispatch/queue.h#L770-L771

Answer (score 1):

You don't create new threads using GCD (`dispatch` family of functions). Those are system queues that already exist and you don't need additional autorelease pools for them.

If you were to manually use `NSThread` or `Thread` in Swift, then you would have to worry about that, but generally you don't need this for even relatively advanced background processing.

Comment: that sounds sensible to me, but there were so many examples around the net that included autoreleasepool blocks...

So, if I understand well, the first autoreleasepool in my example is also unnecessary. Is that correct ?

Comment: This isn't even required for `NSThread` anymore, or even pthreads. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30519746/97337 And of course it also isn't needed for queues you create (so not just system-created queues). You only need to create autoreleasepools now when you're going to create a lot of temporary objects that you want to control the lifetime of (usually to prevent a spike in memory due to loops).

Comment: Incorrect on both points: 1)  GCD do not create autorelease pools for all their queues; only queues where you ask for automatic pools. 2) the automatic autoreleasepool for NSThread/Thread/pthread is an emergency fallback that won't be emptied until thread dies, so depending on that behavior will lead to memory bloat in your app.